Power Bi field parameter using same measure multipe times with different caption / not working proper
for concept reasons I'm def Fieldparm with the same measure but with differnet captions.
the "table" from the fieldparameter has 100+ entries, so in Order to prevent making 100+ different measures I have use only one.
When I bring the fieldparameter to a table, all Measures show the same caption.
A simplified model of the problem
Measure
TestMeasure = RANDBETWEEN(0,100)

Def. of Fieldparameter:
Parameter = {
    ("Kat1", NAMEOF('Measure'[TestMeasure]), 0),
    ("Kat2", NAMEOF('Measure'[TestMeasure]), 1)
}


Is there any way to display the correct caption?
Additional Tools I can use:
Tabular editor
DAX Studio
